# Passing foreign key value to Choice in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm a bit confused on how Forms and ModelForms work, I want to create colored buttons based on a field value while creating a form.

```
{% for category in form.category  %}
<label class="colored-icon btn btn-default btn-sm" style="background-color: {{ category.color }}">
    {{ category.choice_label|slice:"1" }}
    {{ category.tag }}
</label>
{% endfor %}
```

The problem is that `category.color`obviously doesn't have value I need.

My form is based on a "Transaction" model. I need to somehow access "color" attribute from "Category" model, which looks like this:

`forms.py`

```
class TransactionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Transaction
```

`models.py`

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, default='Unspecified')

class Category(models.Model):
    color = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

`views.py`

```
def index(request):
    form = TransactionForm(request.POST)
    new_transaction = form.save()
    context = {
        'form': form,
    }

return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

What's the proper way to select and pass "category.color" to each field I'm creating?

Thanks.

Comment: How do you save `Transcation` object? Could you show your views.py?

Comment: @torm, I've added my views.py file contents

Comment: Where do you render the template (from top of your question)?

Comment: if you do {{ form.category }} does it not spit out the correct select statement with all related 'category's, or you just want the 'color' aspect of Category?

Comment: @torm, edited question again, added part where I render then template

Comment: @warath-coder it does display all categories I need, but I need both categories and their respective colors from DB

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    color = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s - %s' % (self.OtherFieldName, self.color)
```

that way inside the select should look like this

```
<option value='CategoryID'>OtherFieldName_value - color_value</option>
```

Comment: Thanks, it certainly does look like this, but I have no idea how to pass this color to add color value for this select.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I've figured out a way to do so with modified @warath-coder answer. I wasn't able to access "_value" property if it was a way to go, so I had to implement "split" filter and use it to split value I've got and use "color" part of this value.

`models.py`

```
class Category(models.Model):
    color = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s - %s' % (self.OtherFieldName, self.color)
```

`split_filter.py`

```
@register.filter(name='split')
def split(value, arg):
    return value.split(arg)
```

`index.html`

```
{% with category.choice_label|split:"-" as label %}
<label class="btn btn-default btn-sm" style="background-color: {{ label.1 }}">
  {{ label.0 }}
  {{ category.tag }}
</label>
{% endwith %}
```